# Is there a way to calculate repeating calculations only once in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I use JDBC to query where the query contains the same calculations several times.
for example:

```
SELECT 
DATE(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(my_time + timezone_offset * 60), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00')),
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(my_time + timezone_offset * 60), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00')))
FROM my_table;
```

Can I somehow do it without making the calculations several times?

(It will make performance better, and also the code will look cleaner)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table (sub-query in FROM clause):

```
select mydate, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mydate)
from
(
  SELECT 
  DATE(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(my_time + timezone_offset * 60), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00')) as mydate,
  FROM my_table
);
```