# How to perform SQL without duplicate calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, timestampdiff

I have following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM tier  
WHERE  
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, now(), FROM_UNIXTIME(expireAt) )  < 72
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, now(), FROM_UNIXTIME(expireAt) )  > 0
```

You can see, that there is a `TIMESTAMPDIFF` calculation twice.

Is there any way how to perform this calculation only once?

Comment: Maybe a [derived table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094753/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-repeating-calculations-only-once-in-sql) can help?

Comment: If you have UNIX timestamps in your database you're not helping yourself here. MySQL can index `DATETIME` columns and then it's easy to do a `BETWEEN` on some `DATE_SUB(...)` values. These have the advantage of being indexed. What you have here requires a very painful table scan.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur Good point, removed that. I think your solution is right on point.

Comment: Please explain the logic that you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `between`. Since `between` includes range boundaries, instead of 0 and 72 you need to use 1 and 71.

```
SELECT *
FROM tier  
WHERE  
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, now(), FROM_UNIXTIME(expireAt) ) between 1 and  71
```

Answer (score 2):

CTE at rescue:

```sql
With CTE as
(
SELECT 
  *,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, now(), FROM_UNIXTIME(expireAt) ) as t
FROM tier  
)
Select *
From cte
Where t > 0 and t < 72
```

Be aware, this is not index friendly.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you want everything that has expired in the past 72 hours:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tier  
WHERE expire_at < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and
      expire_at > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 72 * 60 * 60;
```

If you really want this aligned on the *hours*, you can still do the operations on the Unix timestamp values:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tier  
WHERE expire_at < FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() / (60 * 60)) * 60 * 60
      expire_at > FLOOR( (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 72 * 60 * 60) / (60 * 60))) * 60 * 60;
```

Some important notes:

- If you are storing date/time values as Unix timestamps, often there is no need to convert to `date`/`datetime` values for calculations.
- For performance reasons, you want to avoid functions on the column, these impede the optimizer.
- By contrast, expressions on "constants" (including the current date/time) should only be evaluated once by the query engine.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:**

It is never a good idea to make a calcultion on a field **expireAt** and then compaire it with 1 or 2 constants. In this case MySQL must do this calculation on each ROW and this will bee a **FULL TABLESCAN** and can never be use a INDEX.

Its much better to calculate the range one time and compire this with the field like

```
SELECT *
FROM tier  
WHERE expireAt BETWEEN
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERAVAL 71 HOUR))
AND
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERAVAL 1 HOUR));
```